# How to add a click listener on auto generated Android ListViews

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I added to my class MyActivity the following :

```
private void updateMyList(){
    listing=new ArrayList<listing>();
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Users user=new Users();
        user.setListingName("Name" + i);
        user.setListingPhone("i" + i);
        listing.add(user);
    }
    MyListAdapter lfa = new MyListAdapter(this, listing);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listFeed)).setAdapter(lfa);

}
```

This code generates  10 list views  so I'd like to add a click listener, so when I click on one of the 10 lists, I get a message or sthing.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you couldn't just add an `onItemClickListener` in your loop to your `ListView`. In short, use your `Adapter` to create the list then just attach the listener:

```
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, connections.toArray(new String[connections.size()])));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View item, int position, long id) {

                String item = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
```

This is if you want to know which item in each list was clicked, there is an `setOnClickListener` method as well in case you just want to know whether a `ListView` has been clicked or not.